# Can you attach たち to a verb?

Tags: grammar, syntax, suffixes, plural-suffixes

I was watching an anime and I got stumped on this sentence (Context: the speaker is an old man character explaining the concept of soulmates). "*運命の人同士が出会うとき全身にビビーンと衝撃が走りたちどころに互いを好きで好きでたまらなくなる*" The part that confuses me is the **走りたち**. From what I know, you can only attach the plural suffix **たち** to nouns, specifically human nouns. And it's less like a pluralizing suffix and more like a "*noun* + and company" phrase. So what's it doing after the i-stem of a verb? I think putting verbs into the i-stem makes them into nouns, but that doesn't really makes sense of the sentence. What's this たち supposed to mean here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a case of incorrect parsing. It is not 走りたち+どころに but 走り+たちどころに. However, note that たちどころ starts a new clause. So the sentence can be broken down to [運命の人同士が出会うとき全身にビビーンと衝撃が走り][たちどころに互いを好きで好きでたまらなくなる]. A comma right there may have helped you parse that.

Now for the word.　[たちどころに](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1%E3%81%A9%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E3%81%AB) means "on the spot", "instantaneously".
The translation would be something like "When those who are fated meet each other, a shockwave runs through their entire body, and on that spot, they will not be able to resist loving each other."